# To concat 2 input field values and perform POST operation in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an component called `add-customer`. Which is having 2 input fields
 **1)firstname** 
**2)lastname**.
I want to concat **1)firstname** **2)lastname**  to an variable called **fullname**. Then i want perform **POST** operation on clicking **SAVE** button .Because there is an field for **fullname** in the **DB**

> Below is my component CODE

**HTML**

```
 <div>
   <h2 color="primary">Add Customer</h2>
     <form [formGroup]="addCusForm">

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstname" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.firstname.hasError('required')">
          Please enter first name
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastname" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.lastname.hasError('required')">
              Please enter last name
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field> 

    <button mat-flat-button type="submit" (click)="onaddCustomer()">Save</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
  import { Component, OnInit, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  import {
      FormBuilder,
      FormControl,
      FormGroup,
      Validators,
   } from '@angular/forms';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  import { IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';
  import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';

  @Component({
    selector: 'asd-add-customer',
    templateUrl: './add-customer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-customer.component.css'],
  })

 export class AddCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
 public addCusForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
          public customersService: CustomersService) {}

 public ngOnInit(): void {
 this.addCusForm = this.fb.group({
   firstname: [null, [Validators.required],
   lastname: [null, [Validators.required],
   });
 }

 public onaddCustomer(): void {
   this.markAsDirty(this.addCusForm);
   this.someContact = this.addCusForm.value;
   this.customersService.addContact(this.someContact);
 }

  private markAsDirty(group: FormGroup): void {
    group.markAsDirty();
    for (const i in group.controls) {
    group.controls[i].markAsDirty();
   }
 }

}
```

I got some example  for concating the 2 string after fetching from the server, But i want to concat  then i want POST it to server.

Answer (score 1):

I have created working example for you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-98wdzu

[image]

ts file

```
public addCusForm: FormGroup;

  fullname :any;
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

 }

 public ngOnInit() {
     this.addCusForm = this.fb.group({
      firstname: [null, [Validators.required]],
      lastname: [null, [Validators.required]]
      });
 }

  public onaddCustomer() {
    console.log("addCusForm",this.addCusForm.value);
    this.fullname =this.addCusForm.value.firstname + this.addCusForm.value.lastname;
  }
```

update:->

```
this.someContact = this.addCusForm.value;
   this.customersService.addContact(this.someContact);//because you are send form value only. For example firstname, lastname wise. so you dont need like this.
```

to

```
let requestData={fullname:this.fullname};
   this.customersService.addContact(requestData);
```

Comment: conctinationis happening, But the `fullname` is not goinf to `DB`.

Comment: hey man pls change like this fullname. Its just an spell mistake.

Comment: Only firstname and last names are going, fullname is not going to DB.

Comment: Just verified in the **POSTMAN**, The 1st & 2nd name values have gone like this: ( "firstName": "Jhon",
        "lastName": "Doe",)

Comment: I have find your issue please check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185349/discussion-between-empty-soul-and-karnan-muthukumar).

Answer (score 0):

Will this do a job for you?

```
this.customersService.addContact({
  // expand existing object with spread operator to new object
  ... this.addCusForm.value,
  // add field to new object with concatenated other fields
  fullname: `${this.addCusForm.value.fistname} ${this.addCusForm.value.lastname}`
});
```

And yes, you don't need this wrong line: `fullname = firstname + "" + lastname,`

Comment: Let me try...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.addCusForm = this.fb.group({
   firstname: [null, [Validators.required],
   lastname: [null, [Validators.required],
   //remove this line
   //fullname = firstname + "" + lastname,
 });
}

public onaddCustomer(): void {
  this.markAsDirty(this.addCusForm);
  this.someContact = Object.assign(this.addCustForm.value, { fullname: 
  this.addCustForm.value['firstname'] + ' ' + this.addCustForm.value['lastname'] });
  this.customersService.addContact(this.someContact);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one i think its help you:

TS:

```
addCusForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.addCusForm = this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.group ({
        firstname: [null, Validators.required],
   lastname: [null, Validators.required],
      }),
   fullname: new FormControl (null, Validators.required)
   })

   this.addCusForm.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
     this.addCusForm.get('fullname').setValue(this.addCusForm.get('name').get('firstname').value + " " + this.addCusForm.get('name').get('lastname').value)
   })
  }
```

this working code check if helpful for you. or check link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srwprr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I want POST `fullname` along with the form values like this **this.customersService.addContact(this.someContact);**

Comment: @Empty_Soul  i'm edit my answer please check. its work for you?

Comment: i am having many input fields rather than `first` and `last` name.

Comment: Since i was focusing only on concatenation, I poasted `firstname` and `lastname` only.